# UIGestureRecognizer on only one part of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uigesturerecognizer

If you look into the image, you'll see a **textview**, **button** and a **slider**.

I have completed all the steps except for the last one which is, when I tap on the slider, it constantly disappear. I know it disappear because I implemented UITapGestureRecognizer.

I guess my question is, I want the slider to disappear everytime I tap anywhere on the screen but **when I am using the slider, I dont want the slider to disappear** which is happening now every time I release my tap.

I have tried implementing one more UITapGestureRecognizer in sizeRefont with a function to keep sizeRefont.isHidden false but when I do that, the slider will not disappear whenever I tap on the screen.

I tried putting sizeRefont.isHidden = false in sizeRefont action and it doesnt work either.

```
class ResizeController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sizeRefont: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissRefontSize(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@IBAction func sizeRefont(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let fontSize = CGFloat(sizeRefont.value)
    textView.font = UIFont(name: textView.font!.fontName, size: fontSize * 30.0)
}


@IBAction func showSlider(_ sender: Any) {
    sizeRefont.isHidden = false
}


func dismissRefontSize(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.location(in: sizeRefont){
        sizeRefont.isHidden = false
    } else {
        sizeRefont.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

}

There is an error on  **if sender.location(in: sizeRefont)** where it says CGPoint is not convertible to Bool

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML45D.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to do is you need to Adjust the dismissRefontSize() method to to the following :

```
func dismissRefontSize(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
 let location = sender.location(in: view) 
If sizeReFont.frame.contains(location) {
// do nothing
}else {

sizeReFont.isHidden = true 
}
}
```

The other thing you need to adjust is creating the tap recognized in your viewDidLoad() to the following:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action : #selector(dismissRefontSize(_:)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! There is an error. I'll post it shortly

Comment: It's a pleasure. Glade I could help